# rounding the result in alert / 'Surface of a circle'

Tags: geometry, rounding, alert, prompt, pi

could you please help me. in my exercise:

`Write an algorithm which receives the radius of a circle and calculate its surface. (prompt and alert)`

I did next:

const num = prompt("enter radius value");
alert(`the circle area is ${Math.PI * num ** 2}`);

but I would like the eventual result would be rounded to 2digits after point. I tried to use toFixed, but have no idea where to place it

appreciate any help

Comment: you already now how to use variables.
You could make a new variable called `area` to which you assign the math expression above. In the `alert` call you can use `area.toFixed(2)`. (You can also group your expression in paranthesis and call `toFixed` on that, however the code would be easier to read with the extra variable and writing code easy to read and understand is very important: you're making life easier for your future self.

Comment: Thank you so much @GeorgeProfenza : `const num = prompt("enter radius value");
let area = Math.PI * num ** 2;
alert( \`the circle area is ${area.toFixed(2)}\`);`